# jQuery.on() fails to work with stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, stoppropagation

I want to stop `func()` from being executed when I click the inner div.

this is the html:

```
    <div onclick="func()">
       <div id="inner-div">
          I'm an inner div
       </div>
     </div>
```

This code will stop propagation:

```
$('#inner-div').bind("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

**This code fails to stop propagation:**

```
$(document).on("click", '#inner-div' , function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

How do I do it?

Comment: can you explain how to do it? where do I check it? In the html or in the js?

Comment: See Adeneo's answer, i mean that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And to solve it you could do:

```
<div onclick="func(event, this)">
   <div id="inner-div">
      I'm an inner div
   </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
function func(e, that) {
    if (e.target === that) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9MaS/)

or use jQuery and remove the inline handler (as the question is tagged jQuery)

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="inner-div">
      I'm an inner div
   </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#parent', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9MaS/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Stopping propagation from a delegated handler will not work, since the event has *already* propagated up the document tree in order for that delegated handler to run.

This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

> Since the `.live()` method handles events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of
>   live events.

`on()` and `delegate()` behave the same as `live()` in this context, only with an ancestor element instead of the document itself. In all cases, it is too late to stop the event from propagating from the target element.